# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'AnyObject?' with no arguments Swift 4.2

Tags: swift, firebase

```
var loggedInUser = AnyObject?() //Cannot invoke initializer for type 'AnyObject?' with no arguments
```

don't know why it's giving me that error I am new to swift

```
var databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
var storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()

// structure definition goes here
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.loggedInUser = Auth.auth()?.currentUser
    self.databaseRef.child("user_profiles").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value) { (snapshot:DataSnapshot) in
```

---

```
var databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
var storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()

// structure definition goes here
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.loggedInUser = Auth.auth()?.currentUser

    self.databaseRef.child("user_profiles").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value) { (snapshot:DataSnapshot) in
```

Comment: Why are you trying to create an `AnyObject`?

Comment: Why not declare loggedInUser as optional and initialize it to nil?

Answer (score 1):

The Firbase type is User so declare it as that

```
var loggedInUser: User?
```

Comment: @AbrahamJ not very helpful, you need to explain what and how it did not work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55800128/cannot-use-optional-chaining-on-non-optional-value-of-type-auth

Answer (score 0):

AnyObject can't be initialize the way you did. you can declare as a optional variable

declare this way :

```
var loggedInUser : AnyObject?
```

Comment: update your first post and let us see your full code and error line

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55800128/cannot-use-optional-chaining-on-non-optional-value-of-type-auth