# Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'Auth'

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, option-type

```
var loggedInUser: User?

let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()


// structure definition goes here
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.loggedInUser = Auth.auth()?.currentUser//Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'Auth' 

    self.databaseRef.child("user_profiles").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value) { (snapshot:DataSnapshot) in //'observeSingleEventOfType(_:withBlock:)' has been renamed to 'observeSingleEvent(of:with:)'

        self.name.text = snapshot.value!["name"] as? String//Type 'Any' has no subscript members
        self.handle.text = snapshot.value!["handle"] as? String//Type 'Any' has no subscript members

        //initially the user will not have an about data

        if(snapshot.value!["about"] !== nil)
        {
            self.about.text = snapshot.value!["about"] as? String
        }

        if(snapshot.value!["profile_pic"] !== nil)//Type 'Any' has no subscript members
        {
            let databaseProfilePic = snapshot.value!["profile_pic"]
                as! String//Type 'Any' has no subscript members

            let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: databaseProfilePic)!)

            self.setProfilePicture(self.profilePicture,imageToSet:UIImage(data:data!)!)
        }

        //self.imageLoader.stopAnimating()
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

var loggedInUser = AnyObject?()//this code was giving me an error 
//Cannot invoke initializer for type 'AnyObject?' with no arguments
```

Then I switched it to:

```
var loggedInUser: User?// still giving me errors
```

Comment: Please [search on the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%27Cannot+use+optional+chaining+on+non-optional+value+of+type%27+%5Bswift%5D) before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Auth.auth()?.currentUser` with `Auth.auth().currentUser`.

`auth()` returns a non-optional type, so you can't use optional chaining with it.

Take a look at its [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/Auth#/c:objc(cs)FIRAuth(cm)auth), it returns an object of type `Auth` not `Auth?`.

Answer (score 0):

1- You should declare the user like

```
var loggedInUser: FIRUser?
```

Then assign it in `viewDidLoad`

```
loggedInUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
```

2- `snapshat.value` is of type `Any` so you need

```
let value = snapshot.value as! [String:Any]  // you can do [String:String]  if all values are strings 
self.name.text = value["name"] as! String
self.handle.text = value["handle"] as! String
```

3- Don't use `NS` ( use `Data` instead `NSData` ) stuff and avoid `contentsOfURL`

```
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: databaseProfilePic)!)
```

in loading remote urls as it blocks the main thread consider using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage)